# Better way to attach two ReactiveProperty

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, reactive-property

Im using ReactiveProperty library in my code and from time to time I need to attach two `ReactiveProperty<T>` together maintaining property data synchronized. For example by combining a `ReactivePropertySlim` from a service class to a `ReactiveProperty` in a ViewModel class.

Usually I use the next code:

```cs
// NewProperty is a ViewModel public property
NewProperty = service.Property.ToReactiveProperty<T>();
var propertyDisposable = NewProperty.Subscribe(value => service.Property.Value = value);
```

Not lookup so bad for a single property but when the number gets high the code gets to.

For now Im using a simple extension method to limit the code repetition.

```cs
public static (IReactiveProperty<T> property, IDisposable cleanup) AttachReactiveProperty<T>(this IReactiveProperty<T> baseProperty)
{
    var newProperty = baseProperty.ToReactiveProperty<T>();
    var cleanup = newProperty.Subscribe(value => baseProperty.Value = value);
    return (newProperty, cleanup);
}
```

I end with a property variable and a IDisposable variable to manage unsubscrition.

```cs
var (pausedProperty, pausedDisposable) = remoteConversion.Paused.AttachReactiveProperty();
NewProperty = pausedProperty;
```

For now the extension is doing his work (less and clear code I think). But is there a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: [OAPH](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/observable-as-property-helper/) is a much cleaner way of dealing with dependent properties, imo.

Comment: Sorry but Im not using ReactiveUI in any way, if this is what you mean. But I give you +10 for comment speed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can use `ToReactiveProperty[Slim]AsSynchronized` extension method that is defined `Reactive.Bindings.Extensions` namespace.

```cs
using Reactive.Bindings;
using Reactive.Bindings.Extensions;

var rp1 = new ReactiveProperty<string>("Init");
ReactiveProperty<string> rp2 = rp1.ToReactivePropertyAsSynchronized(x => x.Value);
ReactivePropertySlim<string> rp3 = rp1.ToReactivePropertySlimAsSynchronized(x => x.Value);
Console.WriteLine("----");
Console.WriteLine(rp1.Value); // Init
Console.WriteLine(rp2.Value); // Init
Console.WriteLine(rp3.Value); // Init

rp1.Value = "Update from rp1";
Console.WriteLine("----");
Console.WriteLine(rp1.Value); // Update from rp1
Console.WriteLine(rp2.Value); // Update from rp1
Console.WriteLine(rp3.Value); // Update from rp1

rp3.Value = "Update from rp3";
Console.WriteLine("----");
Console.WriteLine(rp1.Value); // Update from rp3
Console.WriteLine(rp2.Value); // Update from rp3
Console.WriteLine(rp3.Value); // Update from rp3

// disconnect
rp2.Dispose();
rp3.Dispose();

rp1.Value = "Done";
Console.WriteLine("----");
Console.WriteLine(rp1.Value); // Done
Console.WriteLine(rp2.Value); // Update from rp3
Console.WriteLine(rp3.Value); // Update from rp3
```

See: https://okazuki.jp/ReactiveProperty/features/Work-together-with-plane-model-layer-objects.html#two-way-synchronization

Comment: I will check this today, I miss this part of documentation. If this works, will mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a similar but more clean (I think) way to the the same.

In each reactive classes I usually have some `CompositeDisposable _cleanup` field like this.

```cs
public sealed class SomeClass: IDisposable
{
    private readonly CompositeDisposable _cleanup = new CompositeDisposable();
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cleanup.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then using this basic class contruction and this extension method

```cs
internal static class ReactivePropertyEx
{
    public static IReactiveProperty<T> AttachReactiveProperty<T>(this IReactiveProperty<T> baseProperty, Action<IDisposable> registerDisposable)
    {
        var newProperty = baseProperty.ToReactiveProperty<T>();

        var cleanup = newProperty.Subscribe(value => baseProperty.Value = value);

        registerDisposable(cleanup);

        return newProperty;
    }
}
```

The code ends more simple and elegant. The usage is

```cs
NewProperty = service.Property.AttachReactiveProperty(disposable => disposable.AddTo(_cleanup));
```